# C++ - How to "Fill" a function call and use a default values for arguments

Tags: c++

Let's say a third party library exposes a class.
Its constructor has no default arguments and all arguments are of the same type.

```cpp
class Something{
  public: 
    Something(int a, int b, int c, int d);
};
```

Is there any syntax that would allow to instanciate that class with the same default value for each arguments ?

eg :

```cpp
Something s( sugar_stuff(42) ...) ; // <-> Something s(42,42,42,42);
```

Thanks, Steven

Comment: your `Something` has a private constructor

Answer (score 6):

Write a function:

```
Something createSomething(int v) { 
    return {v,v,v,v};
}
```

PS: I suppose the constructor is actually public not private.

Comment: Well... I don't know about "no syntax". This is C++ after all https://wandbox.org/permlink/yqkuvhOXqEOHOhEC

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica cant access the link

Comment: Weird... Hopefully https://godbolt.org/z/Y3xja4K8a fares better

Comment: @StoryTeller cool stuff :)

Comment: @PaulSanders it was merely a counter example for a rough and wrong over-simplification I made in the answer. I hope its not meant to be actually used anywhere

Comment: @PaulSanders - Well, I did use such tricks in the past. Wrote tests that checked things via this back door. The plus side was that the published library didn't have any "friend for testing" or "public for testing" blemishes.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SomethingElse : public Something{
public:
    using Something::Something;
    SomethingElse (int a)
    : Something{a, a, a, a}
    {}
};
```

Comment: this creates a `SomethingElse` not a `Something`

Comment: Yes this is one of ways to do it and it has disadvantage of introducing new type. Personally I prefer `463035818_is_not_a_number`s way, but I've provided this answer as possible alternative.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to create a new function that calls the original function:

```
void Something_new(int a = 42, int b = 42, int c = 42, int d = 42){
Something(a,b,c,d);
}
```

Comment: It's a third party library.

Answer (score -3):

My favorite is

```
class Something {
    int a = 0, b = a, c = b, d = c;
}

Something x0{};
Something x1{1};
Something x2{1, 2};
Something x3{1, 2, 3};
Something x4{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

You can also initialize everything to `a` or `0` instead of the previous member if you prefer that.

---

https://godbolt.org/z/Yxj883zsr

```
x4:
        .long   1
        .long   2
        .long   3
        .long   4
x3:
        .long   1
        .long   2
        .long   3
        .long   3
x2:
        .long   1
        .long   2
        .long   2
        .long   2
x1:
        .long   1
        .long   1
        .long   1
        .long   1
x0:
        .zero   16
```

Comment: As commented under other answer `Something` comes from third party library, so can't be altered. This is clearly stated in question in fist sentence.

Comment: @MarekR Time to buy a new library.